# Powershell: how to backup a list of databases

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-backups

I have a script which successfully backups all databases in SQL Server:

```
cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\DEFAULT\Databases
foreach($database in (Get-ChildItem))
{
$dbName = $database.Name
Backup-SqlDatabase -Database $dbName -BackupFile "C:\Backup\$dbName.bak"
}
```

I want to to backup a limited list of databases, instead of all of them.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need the list that you want to backup, or some way to filter the databases, and then just toss a simple If/Then in there.

```
cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\DEFAULT\Databases
$DBList = Get-Content 'C:\Path\To\DBList.txt'
foreach($database in (Get-ChildItem))
{
    $dbName = $database.Name
    If($DBList -contains $dbName){
        Backup-SqlDatabase -Database $dbName -BackupFile "C:\Backup\$dbName.bak"
    }
}
```

Or you can alter the If/Then to use some logic if you prefer (every DB that starts with VM):

```
If($dbName -like "VM*")
```

or everything that references Server008 or Server006

```
If($dbName -match ".*?Server00(6|8).*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\DEFAULT\Databases
foreach($database in (Get-ChildItem))
{
    $dbName = $database.Name
    If ($dbName -eq "databaseName" –OR $dbName -eq "anotherDatabaseName")
    {
        Backup-SqlDatabase -Database $dbName -BackupFile "C:\Backup\$dbName.bak"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the names of the databases in the $arrDBName.

```
$arrDBName = @("Name1","Name2","Name3")
cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\DEFAULT\Databases
foreach($database in (Get-ChildItem))
{
$dbName = $database.Name
If ($arrDBName -contains $dbName) {
    Backup-SqlDatabase -Database $dbName -BackupFile "C:\Backup\$dbName.bak"
}
}
```